# mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server on windows server 2000

Tags: php, sql-server

I have application with php. I want to connect on sql server 2000

This is my code:

```
$server = '10.0.0.26';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'username', 'password');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
```

But I have error like

> Message: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: 10.0.0.8. I
>   make sure that i use correct username, password and ip.

When I use this code to connect sql server 2012. I did't get any error.

I run my php using apache on linux.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter should be SERVERNAME not Server's IP as it is mention in the [PHP DOCS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php)

*eg ( from php manual)*

```
$server = 'KALLESPC\SQLEXPRESS';

// Connect to MSSQL

    $link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'phpfi');
    
    if (!$link) {
        die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file:

```
; Use NT authentication when connecting to the server
mssql.secure_connection = On
```

If you have secure_connection = On, make sure that you provide valid credentials in the properties for Apache service in the System Services box. Then you should not send DB username and password from your script to MSSQL Server.

If you want to use specific credentials from a PHP script, then set

```
mssql.secure_connection = Off
```

in your php script.